# Is it rude to bring our own baby food into a restaurant?

Tags: australia, children, etiquette, restaurants

Our baby is too small to eat adult’s food, so we bring our own baby food with us when we dine in a restaurant, which supplies us with a baby high chair.

I am wondering if it is rude to bring our own baby food into a Korean / Japanese restaurant in Australia?

Comment: Any restaurant manager who finds that rude will get nothing from me but a very bad review.

Comment: I'd also consider whether they may be annoyed at you bringing a baby into a restaurant, depending on how up-market the restaurant is. See [jpatokal's](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/14317/324) mention of "or, like us when eating out with our two-year-old, apologize for mess".

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, true, can I please ask how you apologize for mess? Write a letter or ask the manager to say it for you?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you talk about a baby, 'eating' nothing but milk or the mashed food pots, it is not rude in the least and the norm in restaurants all over.

When the child becomes old enough to eat normal food, contact the restaurant if you are not sure the restaurant has something suitable.
Many restaurants will do some simple meat and chips, in the kind that kids in the area will be able to get in almost all restaurants in the country.
If you prefer your kids to eat something healthy instead, they might be able to offer smaller portions of 'normal for the restaurant' food or what they give their own children.
Other restaurants will prefer you to bring your own food for the child that they can heat for you.

It is never rude to ask.

Comment: Yeah, when in doubt, ask. I totally agree with this.

Comment: I also asked for warm water to prepare baby food, and waiters were always happy to help (not on Australia though).